# Writing to a file a struct of vectors

Tags: c++, file, vector, struct

so I got a simple struct like this:

```
struct scores
{
    std::vector<double> max_score,min_score;
    std::vector<string> names;
};

scores sc;
```

then I create: the vector *sc.names* containing several strings and do the same for the *max/min_scores* containing the scores.

---

Now, I just can't figure out how to write to a file all 3 vectors side by side (columns) like this:

name1 max_score1 min_score1

name2 max_score2 min_score2

...

```
std::ofstream testwrite;
testwrite.open("test.txt");

testwrite << std::setprecision(4);
testwrite << std::fixed;
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = sc.max_score.begin();it != sc.max_score.end();++it)
{
    testwrite << *it << "\n";
}

testwrite.close();
```

Comment: Unless there's a reason for 3 separate vectors you might consider grouping the 3 values in a struct and creating a vector of that struct instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're sure that the vectors are of the same length, you can just iterate over the indices:

```
for (int i=0; i < sc.max_score.length(); ++i)
  testwrite << sc.names[i] << " " << sc.max_score[i] << ... << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks Pavel, it works, but .length() should be swapped with .size()